# How to redirect thumbnail image to main image in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, redirect, thumbnails

How to redirect thumbnail image to main image? Its giving me 404 error message. I want to redirect my-image-300x300.jpg to my-image.jpg. How its possible?

Comment: can you share url where you want this feature?

Comment: Sorry, sir but i cant share url. I just want to any image with 300x300.jpg redirect to main image. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That main image is known as Featured image.
You need to upload the image as featured image, also you need to check whether your theme supports featured image or not.
 It is possible that you may be using a theme that does not support featured images. In that case, you can add featured image support to your theme. If you are comfortable editing theme files and know your way around a little CSS, then you can do it yourself.

To add featured image support in a WordPress theme, you need to add this line of code in your theme’s functions.php file:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

For more reference you can check this [link](http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-add-featured-image-or-post-thumbnails-in-wordpress/)

Comment: I sifted my site to new server. In old site there is images with 300x300.jpg but in new site there is not and no use of it. so old image giving  404 error through google. so i want to all images with 300x300.jpg to main image it can be possible with htaccess or javascript but dont know how?